# I am facing the error parameter Id is missing,while conga composer from VF page button click

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-controller, conga, conga-composer

when i select the records in vf page ,after click on the VF Button the conga should be call along with id for generating the PDF but on button click the window is opening but showing error that "ID Parameter is missing" ?
how to over come the issue?
your reply will be appricated ,please reply asap.

vfpage:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" action="{!GenerateInvoice}"  onclick="openConga(setOfIds)" reRender="table1"/>

<script>
function openConga(setOfIds){
  if(setOfIds !=Null){
  var Formastring=setOfIds.splits(',');
  var joinIds=Formastring.join("'|'");
  var removeSpace=joinIds.replace(" ","");
  var removeLeft=removeSpace.replace("[","");
  var removeRight=removeLeft.replace("]","");
  var finalSetIds=removeRight;
   var CongaUrl ="/apex/APXTConga4__Conga_Composer?sessionId={!$API.Session_ID}"
+"&serverUrl={!$API.Partner_Server_URL_290}&Id={!Payment_Id}"
+"&QVar1Id=[sql1221]a186C0000007yB3?pv1="
+ finalSetIds
+"&TemplateId={QVar1}";
 window.open(CongaUrl, "Conga","menubar=no,height=600,width=800");

  }
}
</script>
```

controller:

```
[‎28-‎01-‎2019 12:13]  Sakhare, Ankita:  
public PageReference GenerateInvoice() {
    selectedEsr = new List < Payment__c > ();
    for (wrappayment wp: paymentList) {
        if (wp.selected == true) {
            Payment_Id = wp.pay.id;

        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have followed this Link :::https://www.eternussolutions.com/2015/09/07/hack-of-the-day-simplified-document-merging-with-conga-visualforce/

Answer (score 1):

You should call the JavaScript method from `onComplete` instead of `onclick`.
Because before your action complete his exceution you JS method get called with blank Id parameter

```
<apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" action="{!GenerateInvoice}"  oncomplete="openConga(setOfIds, '{!Payment_Id}')" reRender="table1"/>
```

Also, I suggest you pass the ID in parameters as if you are not rerendering that section you will still get the same exception.

Comment: Thanks for your reply@tushar Sharma but this logic is not working,please give me idea any other way ?

Comment: @hari `Payment_Id` you might not be getting value in this. Check if you are getting correct value here.

Comment: SharmaI have checked in the controller payement_Id is getting there

Comment: ,I have tried another way also, The conga page is getting there,But Facing error Parameter Id missing Like  :<Script Language="JavaScript"> 
             function openConga() 
                { 
                    window.open('{!URLFOR($Action.Payment__c.Generate_PDF, Payment_Id)}', '','scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes, toolbar=no,location=yes,status=yes');
       
        </Script>

Comment: Button :Button:<apex:commandButton value="Generate Invoice" action="{!GenerateInvoice}"  onclick="openConga()" reRender="table1"/>

Comment: Controller: public PageReference GenerateInvoice() 
            {
            selectedEsr = new List<Payment__c>();
            for(wrappayment wp : paymentList)
                {
                    if(wp.selected == true) 
                    {  Payment_Id=wp.pay.id; 
 }
        }
         
        return null;
            }

Comment: @hari it would be better if you add these details in your question.